# Converting list nested under two dictionaries to DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pandas

I am trying to create a data frame in Python with Pandas that involves nested dictionaries and lists of lists. I looked through other questions about converting nested dictionaries, but I couldn't find a sufficient answer.

I have a dictionary, which for example, is an activity book that keeps track of extracurricular school lessons. In this case, there are two lessons, and each of the lessons is its own dictionary nested under the activity book dictionary. Each lesson dictionary contains a list of lists of the activities by each person, organized by month. The amount of students performing an activity each month is variable, but the structure is always Student-Activity-Minutes. For example:

```
activity_dict = {

'lesson1' : {  'january' : [['Todd', 'Running', 30],['Christy', 'Studying', 25],['Alex','Soccer', 10]],
               'february' : [['Jim', 'Bobsledding', 5],['Frank', 'Jogging',8]]},

'lesson2' : {'february' : [['Todd', 'Running', 18],['John', 'Studying', 3],['Don','Soccer', 40]],
              'march' : [['Tom', 'Bobsledding', 10],['Sam', 'Yoga', 42]],
              'april' : [['Julie', 'Biking', 20],['Chris', 'Baseball', 10]]}
}
```

I am trying to get an output that for each student's activity, ColA = Lesson #, ColB = Month, ColC = Student, ColD = Activity, and ColE = Minutes. Sample output would be:

```
Lesson # Month Student Activity Minutes
Lesson 1 February Jim Bobsledding 5
Lesson 1 February Frank Jogging 8
Lesson 2 February Todd Running 18
```

I have found a way to create a dataframe of Columns C through E, but I am unable to include Columns A and B.

My code right now is the following:

```
import pandas

activity_log = []

for lesson, all_activities in activity_dict.items():
    for month, month_activities in all_activities.items():
        activity_log.append(pandas.DataFrame(month_activities))
```

How can I update this to include the dictionary keys (lesson and month) as Columns A and B? I'm not sure if changing the list of lists to a dictionary would help, but I have kept it as a list since that is how I received the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to convert the dict of dicts of list of lists into a list of lists:

```
In [99]: [(lesson, month, name, activity, minutes) 
          for lesson, dct in activity_dict.items() 
          for month, vals in dct.items() 
          for name, activity, minutes in vals]
Out[99]: 
[('lesson2', 'april', 'Julie', 'Biking', 20),
 ('lesson2', 'april', 'Chris', 'Baseball', 10),
 ('lesson2', 'february', 'Todd', 'Running', 18),
 ('lesson2', 'february', 'John', 'Studying', 3),
 ('lesson2', 'february', 'Don', 'Soccer', 40),
 ('lesson2', 'march', 'Tom', 'Bobsledding', 10),
 ('lesson2', 'march', 'Sam', 'Yoga', 42),
 ('lesson1', 'january', 'Todd', 'Running', 30),
 ('lesson1', 'january', 'Christy', 'Studying', 25),
 ('lesson1', 'january', 'Alex', 'Soccer', 10),
 ('lesson1', 'february', 'Jim', 'Bobsledding', 5),
 ('lesson1', 'february', 'Frank', 'Jogging', 8)]
```

Then use `pd.DataFrame` to build the DataFrame from the list of lists:

```
In [98]: pd.DataFrame([(lesson, month, name, activity, minutes)
                       for lesson, dct in activity_dict.items() 
                       for month, vals in dct.items() 
                       for name, activity, minutes in vals], 
             columns=['Lesson', 'Month', 'Name', 'Activity', 'Minutes'])
Out[98]: 
     Lesson     Month     Name     Activity  Minutes
0   lesson2     april    Julie       Biking       20
1   lesson2     april    Chris     Baseball       10
2   lesson2  february     Todd      Running       18
3   lesson2  february     John     Studying        3
4   lesson2  february      Don       Soccer       40
5   lesson2     march      Tom  Bobsledding       10
6   lesson2     march      Sam         Yoga       42
7   lesson1   january     Todd      Running       30
8   lesson1   january  Christy     Studying       25
9   lesson1   january     Alex       Soccer       10
10  lesson1  february      Jim  Bobsledding        5
11  lesson1  february    Frank      Jogging        8
```

Comment: Excellent. Trying this now, will respond as soon as possible!

Comment: This works! Quick question, why is importing pandas as pd so common? Is it just that pd is much more convenient?

Comment: I think it has two advantages: it saves on typing (if you reference a lot of Pandas functions or classes) and it makes the code more readable.